# limit elevation ETOPO1 matlab

Tags: matlab, maps, elevation

For a map with ETOPO, how to limit elevation [Z] such that the plotted marker and name are not covered by the map?

Right now, my marker and name is covered by the elevation. I tried editing [Z], a 1200 x 1950 double, which is madness, and I know this is not the way to alter the elevation. Any ideas?

```
% Creating figure
figure

% Construct map axes for region
worldmap australia

% Returning the map projection structure from the current map axes
mstruct = gcm;

% Defining limits for lat and long - adjusting map axis
latlim = mstruct.maplatlimit;
lonlim = mstruct.maplonlimit;

% Read ETOPO file within the specified lat and long limits
% "Z" is data grid, an array of elevations
% "refvec" is the three-element referencing vector
[Z, refvec] = etopo(etopoFile,2, latlim, lonlim);

% Plotting marker on map
plotm(-37.814, 144.96332, '.k','markersize',8)

% Naming on map
textm(-37.814, 144.96332,point name,'FontSize',12)

% Displaying map data, with extracted etopo value
geoshow(Z, refvec, 'DisplayType', 'surface');

% Color the map based on the terrain elevation data, Z. 
demcmap(Z, 500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the value of Z. You should use the `plot3m` function which takes an extra argument for altitude.

```
h = plot3m(lat,lon,z)
```

see https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/plot3m.html.

Then you can prescribe a sufficiently high altitude for your text and marker.